# How to show dropdownlist value on edit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

this is my Question extension to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526814/how-to-get-the-string-from-dropdown-list)..

Here I am able to add the Dropdown list value to the Grid.. perfectly..

Ex: in my Dropdownlist box I have A B C D items..

When I add any Item I am displaying the grid and I am reloading my page.

My grid have two columns one is added Dropdownlist value.. other is some other text value..

each row in my grid have Edit button..

When I click Edit I am reloading my page to edit this selected dropdownlist value..

when I click Edit I need to show what ever the Dropdownlist value I have in the grid I need to show in the Dropdownlist..

so that user knows he has this dropdown value..

please let me know if any body not undrestood my question..

thanks

My Controler code..

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
               // _viewModel.ObnCategoryTextComponent = _obnRepository.GetObnCategoryById(id.Value);
                 var data = _obnRepository.GetSingle<ObnCategory>(id.Value);
                string selectedValue = data.ObnCategoryName;
                _viewModel.ServiceTypeListAll = new SelectList(_bvRepository.GetAllServiceTypes().OrderBy(n => n.ServiceTypeName), "ServiceTypeName", "ServiceTypeName", selectedValue);
                // _viewModel.Category = data.ObnCategoryName;
            }
            return PartialView("Index",_viewModel);
        }
```

My View is..

```
 <%=Html.DropDownList("ServiceTypeListAll",Model.ServiceTypeListAll)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the appropriate items Selected property to true:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    //string selectedValue = "textOfTheSelectedItem";
    string selectedValue = _bvRepository.GetServiceType(id)  // I only guess, that would be your repository access...
    _viewModel.ServiceTypeListAll = new SelectList(_bvRepository.GetAllServiceTypes().ToList().OrderBy(n => n.ServiceTypeName).ToList(), "ServiceTypeName", "ServiceTypeName", selectedValue);
        return View(_viewModel);
}
```

`selectedValue` must match one of the ServiceTypeNames in the list:

For the following list, `selectedValue` must either be "Item 1" or "Item 2":

```
<select>
    <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, you don't have to change the view. This is handled by the Html Helper automatically

Comment: My dropdown list value not changing anything.. Here is my code I will update.. thanks

Comment: Did you try to simplify the Html Helper code? `<%=Html.DropDownList("ServiceTypeListAll", Model.ServiceTypeListAll)%>`

Comment: Since your loading `selectedValue` from a different repository than the actual list, is it possible, that the list doesn't contain `selectedValue`?

Comment: Yes on Debug I do see the value of SelectedValue.. its from same repository.. not form differnt..thanks

Comment: Then update your code, there you load selectedValue from `_obnRepository` and the list data from `_bvRepository`.

Comment: oopss.. so it wont display then?>

Comment: Ok, maybe I have the solution now :-) Try to rename your DropDown, for example `<%=Html.DropDownList("ServiceTypeListAllDropDown",Model.ServiceTypeListAll)%>`. Does it work then?

Comment: I mean to say if it is different repositroy it wont display? selected value?

Comment: Actually it makes no difference where you get the selected value from, it seemed just strange, that you loaded it from a different repository.  Did you try the renaming? There seems to be some weird behaviour if the DropDownList is named like one of the Model's properties

Comment: Ohh I ill try to change the Dropdownlist value.. 1 min I will update you..thanks

Comment: Yes If i change my dropdown list box name its working now.. why its happend like that?
thanks

Comment: No idea, why it's like this! :D

Comment: :) but thanks for your all time for supporting me Dave.. I appreciate that.. thanks soo much..